# How can I merge a subset of commits and replay the rest from one branch onto another?

Tags: git

I was in this scenario

```
A - B (origin/main)
    \
     V - W - X (origin/feature_branch)
              \
               Y - Z (feature_branch)
```

A commit was added to `origin/main`, and I rebased the feature branch on it:

```
          V' - W' - X' - Y' - Z' (feature_branch)
         / 
A - B - C (origin/main)
    \
     V - W - X (origin/feature_branch)
```

How can I achieve this

```
A - B - C (origin/main)
    \          
     V - W - X - <squash of V',W',X'> - Y'' - Z'' (origin/feature_branch)
```

better yet, with the `squash of V',W',X'` being an actual merge commit with `origin/main`.

Comment: *thank you* for asking the question so clearly and concretely.

Comment: I assume you also want (local) `feature_branch` at `Z''` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout origin/feature_branch           # build the new base:
git merge -s ours --no-commit origin/main    # add the custom merge
git read-tree -um "X'"                       # . with the already-known result
git commit                                   # ...

git rebase --onto @ "X'" feature_branch      # perfectly ordinary rebase
```

I'm assuming your desired tip ref was meant to be just `feature_branch`, not `origin/feature_branch`, if you want to update the remote ref too you can push to it as usual.

Answer (score 0):

First, make `feature_branch` active.

```
git checkout feature_branch
```

Then, reset `feature_branch` to `X`:

```
git reset --hard X
```

Then, apply differences between `X` and `X'` (what you call `<squash of V',W',X'>`), making the work tree identical to that of `X'` (make sure you are in the root directory of the repository):

```
git checkout X' -- .
git commit -m "squash of V', W', X'"
```

Then, apply `Y'` and `Z'`:

```
git cherry-pick Y'
git cherry-pick Z'
```

If you fear that something goes wrong midway and you want a safe way back, replace the first two steps by

```
git checkout -b new_feature_branch X
```

Then the original `feature_branch` will still be at `Z'` and you can reset it to `new_feature_branch` if you are sure that it is correct,

```
git checkout feature_branch
git reset --hard new_feature_branch
git branch -d new_feature_branch
```

or simply delete `new_feature_branch` if somehing is wrong, and start over:

```
git checkout feature_branch
git branch -D new_feature_branch  # -D is "force delete"
```

Finally, fast-forward `origin/feature_branch` from `X` to `Z''`:

```
git push
```